# Syntax error at line 18 : `<<' is not matched

Tags: shell-script

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
stty intr ^C erase ^H kill ^U
p_id=`ps -ef|grep iucmh|grep iuc|grep MSC015|grep START|awk -F" " '{print $2}'`

vLogin=`echo "iucmh/iucmh123@4s_MH"`

if [ -z "$p_id" ]; then
     sqlplus -s ${vLogin} <<EOF
     set pagesize 0 
     feedback off 
     verify off 
     heading off 
     echo off;
     UPDATE  IUC_CON_PARAMETERS
     SET F_PARAM_VALUE=0
     WHERE F_PARAM_NAME LIKE 'MSC015_PROCESS_ID'
     EXIT;
EOF

    echo "Working"
#     fi
else
     echo "Process is already Running"
     fi
```

Running this script I get the following error:

```
Syntax error at line 18 : `<<' is not matched.
```

Comment: DOS newlines? There's no syntax error in the code.

Comment: Why the convoluted ``vLogin=`echo "iucmh/iucmh123@4s_MH"` ``? Just use `vLogin="iucmh/iucmh123@4s_MH"`

Comment: DOS newlines or other whitespace at the end of the 'EOF'? I get a different error message with bash 4.3.30, but a quick search on google hints at the whitespace.

Answer (score -3):

The code is OK and `bash` does not contain the error message you mention.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ bla ]; then
     cat <<EOF
     set pagesize 0 
     feedback off 
     verify off 
     heading off 
     echo off;
     UPDATE  IUC_CON_PARAMETERS
     SET F_PARAM_VALUE=0
     WHERE F_PARAM_NAME LIKE 'MSC015_PROCESS_ID'
     EXIT;
EOF

    echo "Working"
#     fi
else
     echo "Process is already Running"
     fi
```

And verify. So I guess that your message is from the command `sqlplus`.

Comment: But sqlplus login is perfectly working fine ...

Comment: did you verify where this error message is from?

Comment: Guys this one more thing ..this script is running fine in sun .....but not working in hp ...

Comment: No. `sqlplus` does not see the `<<EOF`, so it's the shell erroring out. Check the newlines for DOS line-endings instead.

Comment: You missinterpret how such a script is working. The shell handles <<EOF and it does correctly, see my example. The only explanation is that `sqlplus` does not like the input it is given